# convergence of integral in $L^2$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and $h$ is a bounded function in $\Omega$.
Is it true then $\int h |f_n|^2 \to \int h |f|^2$?

I tried to bound the integrand $|h|| |f_n|^2 - |f|^2 |$ but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$, then there exists $C>0$ s.t. $\|f_n\|_2 \leq C$ for every $n$.

Hence, by Holder's inequality,
$$
\int_\Omega |h| \, (|f_n|^2 - |f|^2)
= \int |h| \, |f_n - f|\, |f_n + f|
\leq \|h\|_\infty \|f_n - f\|_2 (\|f_n\|_2 + \|f\|_2)
$$
and now you are (almost) done.

Comment: What do you mean by "almost"? Is there anything more that I need to show?

Comment: You just have to take the limit :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: notice that $f_n^2 - f^2 = (f_n + f)(f_n - f)$ and use Holder's inequality.

Comment: I am having a harder time with difference of quadratic terms. Could you provide me a hint with that?

Comment: @nan: oh, yeah, sure! let me edit my answer then